# R write function to generate a new column

Tags: r, function, if-statement, for-loop, dataframe

I have a column and I have a criteria. I want to write a function to see the value in that column fall into which category.

```
column:
Risk
0.493
1
2
1.7
1
1.7
0.29
0.493
2
0.493

criteria:
Low
0 0.517
Med
0.517 1.859
High
1.859 Inf

Desired output:
0.493   Low
1   Med
2   High
1.7 Med
1   Med
1.7 Med
0.29    Low
0.493   Low
2   High
0.493   Low
```

I tried to write a function but all come out to the category Med:

```
RiskCat <- function(x) {
for ( i in 1:length(x)){
if ( i <= 0.517 ) {
  print("Reduced")
} else if ( i > 0.517 & i <= 1.859 ){
    print("Med")
} else if ( i > 1.859 ) {
    print("High")
} } }
```

Thanks you for your advice!
or may be somebody can correct my function as it runs, it always printed Med and I can't figure it out.

Comment: @RonakShah actually I want to have a function , so that I can RiskCat(0.7) and it tells me it is Med, so it is not the same question at all, but you can say the concept is similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `cut`

```
cut(df1$Risk, breaks = c(-Inf, 0.517, 1.859, Inf), labels = c("Low", "Med", "High"))
#[1] Low  Med  High Med  Med  Med  Low  Low  High Low 
#Levels: Low Med High
```